# Why do i get an error when trying to run fit neural network

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, model

I am trying to build a neural network. I have a dataframe of 1460 by 73 as a train (X_train), an 1460 (Y_train) for the results . The df is corrected with no blank null or empty values and all features have been turned to float. However when i try to fit the model i get an error that i can't understand. Could someone please help me understand what the problem is?

```
X_test = np.array(test_df).astype(np.float32)
Y_train = np.array(train_df['SalePrice']).astype(np.float32)

train_df = train_df.drop(['SalePrice'], axis=1)
X_train = np.array(train_df).astype(np.float32)
X_train.shape, X_test.shape,Y_train.shape
```

((1460, 73), (1459, 73), (1460,))

```
logging.getLogger("tensorflow").setLevel(logging.ERROR)

tf.random.set_seed(1234)
model = Sequential(
    [
          Dense(units=74, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.1)),
          Dense(units=37, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.1)),
          Dense(units=1, activation='linear')
     ], name="Complex"
)
model.compile(
   
    loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-2),
)


model.fit(
    X_train, Y_train,
    epochs=1000
)


model.predict(test_df)

model.summary()
```

the error i get is this :

```
Epoch 1/1000
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [91], in <cell line: 18>()
      4 model = Sequential(
      5     [
      6           Dense(units=74, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.1)),
   (...)
      9      ], name="Complex"
     10 )
     11 model.compile(
     12    
     13     loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
     14     optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-2),
     15 )
---> 18 model.fit(
     19     X_train, Y_train,
     20     epochs=1000
     21 )
     22 #logit = model(X_test)
     23 #f_x=tf.nn.softmax(logit)
     25 model.predict(test_df)

File ~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py:67, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     65 except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
     66   filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
---> 67   raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     68 finally:
     69   del filtered_tb

File ~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py:54, in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     52 try:
     53   ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 54   tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     55                                       inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     56 except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     57   if name is not None:

InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
      return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
    File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
      exec(code, run_globals)
    File "C:\Users\Manos\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py", line 17, in <module>
      app.launch_new_instance()
    File "C:\Users\Manos\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 976, in launch_instance
      app.start()
    File "C:\Users\Manos\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 712, in start
      self.io_loop.start()
    File "C:\Users\Manos\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py", line 199, in start
      self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
    File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 603, in run_forever
      self._run_once()
    File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1899, in _run_once
      handle._run()
    File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 80, in _run
      self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
    File "C:\Users\Manos\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 508, in dispatch_queue
      await self.process_one()
    File "C:\Users\Manos\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 497, in process_one
      await dispatch(*args)
    File "C:\Users\Manos\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 404, in dispatch_shell
      await result
    File "C:\Users\Manos\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 728, in execute_request
      reply_content = await reply_content
    File "C:\Users\Manos\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\ipykernel\ipkernel.py", line 383, in do_execute
      res = shell.run_cell(
    File "C:\Users\Manos\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\ipykernel\zmqshell.py", line 528, in run_cell
      return super().run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\Manos\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2881, in run_cell
      result = self._run_cell(
    File "C:\Users\Manos\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2936, in _run_cell
      return runner(coro)
    File "C:\Users\Manos\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\IPython\core\async_helpers.py", line 129, in _pseudo_sync_runner
      coro.send(None)
    File "C:\Users\Manos\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3135, in run_cell_async
      has_raised = await self.run_ast_nodes(code_ast.body, cell_name,
    File "C:\Users\Manos\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3338, in run_ast_nodes
      if await self.run_code(code, result, async_=asy):
    File "C:\Users\Manos\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3398, in run_code
      exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
    File "C:\Users\Manos\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_11152\1723988500.py", line 18, in <cell line: 18>
      model.fit(
    File "C:\Users\Manos\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\Manos\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1409, in fit
      tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
    File "C:\Users\Manos\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1051, in train_function
      return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "C:\Users\Manos\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1040, in step_function
      outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "C:\Users\Manos\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1030, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "C:\Users\Manos\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 890, in train_step
      loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "C:\Users\Manos\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 948, in compute_loss
      return self.compiled_loss(
    File "C:\Users\Manos\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\keras\engine\compile_utils.py", line 201, in __call__
      loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    File "C:\Users\Manos\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 139, in __call__
      losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    File "C:\Users\Manos\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 243, in call
      return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\Manos\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 1860, in sparse_categorical_crossentropy
      return backend.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(
    File "C:\Users\Manos\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\keras\backend.py", line 5238, in sparse_categorical_crossentropy
      res = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
Node: 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits'
Received a label value of 611657 which is outside the valid range of [0, 1).  Label values: 163500 240000 239500 130000 277000 79000 225000 220000 157000 204000 134000 168000 611657 92000 240000 124900 280000 200000 87000 158500 110000 119900 109500 157000 133000 91500 201800 83000 52500 266000 147500 93000
     [[{{node sparse_categorical_crossentropy/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_1591]
```

Comment: Change your loss from `tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)` to `tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()`, also..`SparseCategoricalCrossentropy` does not make sense in your case.

Comment: Well first you need to think if this is regression or classification, and choose the loss appropriately, you get an error because this was clearly not done.

Comment: It is an regression problem (trying to predict prices). I will look at the errors , Thanks a lot

Comment: Then mean squared error is the correct loss, not cross entropy.

Comment: @Priniotis Kindly try as mentioned above by AloneTogether and Dr.Snoopy, and let us know if the error still persists. Thank you!

Comment: yes the suggestions from AloneTogether and Dr.Snoopy worked (thanks guys) . Do i have to close the question somehow now ?